# Axis2 webservice client weblogic webservice client jar confilct

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client, weblogic-10.x

My application is a war deployed in weblogic 10. In one of my class, I need to make 2 webservice calls A and W. A is based on AXIS2 using wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar, W is based on weblogic webservice using jars in weblogic. I guess due to the conflict between wstx-asl and weblogic stax implementation, they can not be made at the same time.
Here is the detail of the problem:
1. If I remove wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar from web-inf/lib folder, 
B is OK but A is faild due to exception: ClassCastException:weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamInputFactory
2. If I keep wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar in web-inf/lib folder,
A is OK but B is faild due to the exception:
`[java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.bea.staxb.runtime.internal.BindingContextImpl.createMarshaller(BindingContextImpl.java:65) at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.LiteralSerializerContext.(LiteralSerializerContext.java:54) at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsImpl.createSerializerContext(RuntimeBindingsImpl.java:152) at weblogic.wsee.bind.runtime.internal.RuntimeBindingsImpl.createSerializerContext(RuntimeBindingsImpl.java:168) at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SerializationContextUtil.createSerializerContext(SerializationContextUtil.java:26) at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapEncoder.encodeParts(SoapEncoder.java:179) at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapEncoder.encode(SoapEncoder.java:119) at weblogic.wsee.codec.soap11.SoapCodec.encode(SoapCodec.java:128) at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.CodecHandler.encode(CodecHandler.java:52) at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.CodecHandler.handleRequest(CodecHandler.java:41) at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleRequest(HandlerIterator.java:123) at weblogic.wsee.handler.HandlerIterator.handleRequest(HandlerIterator.java:99) at weblogic.wsee.ws.dispatch.client.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDispatcher.java:101) at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsStub.invoke(WsStub.java:89) at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:331) at 
.........................`

Please advise how to make them successful together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your deployment weblogic.xml file, use the `<prefer-web-inf-classes>` tag and set it to true for the axis2 call. And set it to false for the weblogic web service.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/classloading.html#1082452